# S6 and S6 edge cannot use WIFI while using BLE

Tags: android, wifi, bluetooth-lowenergy

I develop an android app that will use ble and wifi.
I find a issue: S6 and S6 edge cannot use WIFI while using BLE.
The same app it can run well in S4. If I use 3G or 4G instead of wifi in S6 or S6 edge, the app runs well too.
I have google the S6 and S6 edge issues about wifi and "disable phone's wifi power saving mode". But the problem still.
If someone have same issue and fix it, please tell me, thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Does WiFi break while doing BLE scanning? While being connected to a BLE device? Is there any negative effect on BLE? How are you determining WiFi doesn't work? Just by visiting webpages and things like that?

Comment: While being connected to a BLE device, I click home button then click browser to visit internet, browser show a message about cannot visit the page. So I use a terminal emulator to check the internal visit speed, and I found that before I connected to a BLE device, the speed is 8000+ bit/s, but after connected to a BLE device, the speed is 10~40 bit/s.